# GWT Eclipse java plugin: Code assist does't work in event handlers

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I'm working on Eclipse (3.6.2, 3.7.2, 4.2.0) with GWT plugin 2.4.0.

In these days, I found the code assist does not work WITHIN EVENT HANDLERS of an EntryPoint class. I reinstalled whole environment, then it worked at that time. But today it get insane again. I don't see any reason for it.

Does anyone experienced such a phenomenon?

Comment: This happens to me too sometimes.

Comment: And I noticed it occurs on ONLY ONE SPECIFIC EntryPoint class! Other EntryPoint classes are normal...

Comment: And I found that it occurs on both of GWTJavaEditor(part of GWT plugin) and CompilationUnitEditor(not part of GWT plugin). Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

This occurs for me when I haven't imported the various classes yet, like ClickHandler.